# Injecting a button into existing grid

Tags: xaml, uwp

```
// Xaml
<Grid x:Name="_Grid" Width="926" Margin="603,140,391,55">
            
</Grid>

// Code behind
Button hello = new Button();
hello.Content = "Hello World";

_Grid.Children.Add(hello);
```

Trying to inject hello button into _Grid but the following error get shown:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

_Grid was null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue when executing these code before calling InitializeComponent() method. InitializeComponent() method is automatically created and managed by **XAML designer** and it defines everything you see on the Window. Everything done on the window using designers generates code. Every single control added and property set will generate code and that code goes into InitializeComponent() method.

Therefore, if you inject this button before InitializeComponent() method, the Grid don’t generate, it is null. so that it reported the `NullReferenceException` when you use this grid. Please operate these code after calling `InitializeComponent()` method like the following.

```
public MainPage()
        {              
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Button helloBtn = new Button();
            helloBtn.Content = "Hello World";
           _Grid.Children.Add(helloBtn);

        }
```